# If a ? is detected in an answer, could we post a warning?

Tags: feature-request, questions, new-users

We've hinted at similar checks in the past:

- [Automatically warning when adding post containing greetings and signatures?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83465/automatically-warning-when-adding-post-containing-greetings-and-signatures)
- [Add question detection when posting an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30071/add-question-detection-when-posting-an-answer?rq=1)
- [Detecting questions in answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89684/detecting-questions-in-answers)

but at a very simple level, could we not put up a nice red warning when a ? is used in an answer, for low rep users?

This to prevent users who think it's a forum where you just add a question at the bottom....

Comment: downvoter, I'd love to hear a reason against it? or a better solution...

Comment: Asking downvoters to explain that action often attracts additional downvotes. Voting is intended to be anonymous.

Comment: @PolyGeo indeed, but on meta we're here to discuss so it kinda defeats the point. I don't care about rep, I just want this problem solved - as a mod I get way too many flags on ques-answers like this ;)

Comment: Downvoting a question because the OP is asking for feedback doesn't surprise me on Stack Exchange...

Comment: This, in principal, isn't a bad idea, I can think of a few situations where some kind of cautionary pop up, not stopping people from posting just a warning, might work i.e. For link only answers or very short answers that are likely unacceptable on a site. Of course the warnings should go away at say 200 rep because those users should no better by then and it would be annoying for established users.

Comment: @MarkKirby correct, as I said, for low rep users. Just to get those who don't know how it works/ who haven't read the [help]

Comment: This would just try to cover up a symptom. Instead SE should tackle the cause of the problem. I think it would probably already help to rename "Post your answer" field to something else, maybe "Post your solution" (at least on the technical sites).

Comment: I think there would be less false alerts from this heuristics if it wouldn't apply to code blocks (and possibly to quotes and maybe to spoiler blockss as well)

Comment: @MarkMayo possibly SE has hired an army of downvoters in their new 'loop' stategy such that they can change the sentiment on meta (a sentiment which they don't like). When they downvote posts then they can keep on going not listening to them.

Comment: Interesting that the top two answers contain "?" themselves for a reasonable use.

Answer (score 24):

Why do you think an answer shouldn't contain a question mark?

A common technique used in answers, particularly those challenging the underlying assumptions of the question, is the [rhetorical question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhetorical_question).  I predict that, particularly on sites that aren't named "Stack Overflow", the rate of false positives will be high enough to annoy the regulars, while doing nothing to reduce the number of "not an answer"s posted.

Comment: Because the majority of the ones that do are questions, in my experience (mainly on travel.SE). This is also why I specified for low rep users only, to reduce the number of red herrings.

Comment: For those who like to pose rhetorical questions in their answers, or those who are including a question asked in their answer, couldn't they be encouraged to always do that in quote formatting so that those question marks could be easily distinguished from question marks that are part of trying to ask a question in the area reserved for answers?

Answer (score 17):

Can you show some stats that suggest that a question mark in the answer is strongly associated with an answer not appropriate for SE? Is there a possibility of confirmation bias in your claims? Finally, what about ruby methods that ends in `?`, such as `nil?`, `empty?`, etc?

Comment: Just years of experience.  Also yes I noted elsewhere that there will be a few false positives.  A simple A/B test would answer that more than any stats I could provide.

Comment: Good point about the A/B test.

Answer (score -1):

Your proposal may give some false positives, but with just a little refinement I think an algorithm could be found to eliminate most of them.

Examples likely to give false positives are:

- code containing question marks (should always be code formatted);
- quoting a question from the question (should always be quote formatted); and
- rhetorical questions (could be quote formatted to make them stand out)

As soon as text including a question mark is formatted as code or a comment the algorithm could ignore it.

I think this is an excellent feature request because nothing says that *the space reserved for answers should not be used to ask questions* like warning answerers when they appear to be asking one or more questions there.

I think that this warning, if it can be tuned to only give rare false positives, should be applied to answers by all users.  Those experienced in focused Q&A should learn to avoid ever seeing it far quicker than those who are new to the format.

Comment: Quoting a question from the question should be **quote** formatted.

Comment: @AndrewLeach You’re right - corrected